# "in" versus "of"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I hope that both forms shown below are correct.

What is the difference between them and which one seems more natural?

> 1. the initial and final element *in* the expression/clause
> 2. the initial and final element *of* the expression/clause

Comment: I would pick *in* by weight of colloquial usage.  *The first word in the sentence...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is very subtle and not at all important. Both sound natural.

If you want to slide a cigarette paper between them, *of* uses the metaphor of constituent parts, and *in* the metaphor of container of objects.

So you could distinguish them by how much you wish to imply that the expression/clause has fixed, organised, and inevitable internal structure.

For example, the **"subject *of* the sentence"**: there is one of them, and it's exceptional for it not to be there, an inherent part of the structure of a sentence: it is *a formal part*.

But **"the adjectives *in* the sentence"**, as they can be scattered to various points in a sentence of any complexity: they are *contained within* it.

There's a vast plain of middle ground (where your example seems to lie) where it seems to make very little difference.