# Meaning of "Students in all majors" versus "Students of all majors"

Tags: differences, prepositions, american-english

I would like to know the difference between these sentences:

- I want to send an email to students **of** all majors
- I want to send an email to students **in** all majors

How did of/in change the meaning of these sentences?

I've checked the link: [“in” versus “of”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193604/in-versus-of/308705?noredirect=1#comment696658_308705).

Answer (score 1):

Although both sentences are clear, send that email to ...

> ... students **in** all majors.

A student *of* something sounds too much like someone who studies it:

> 1.2   A person who takes an interest in a particular subject:
>   
>     ‘a **student of** the free market’
>   – [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/student#student__8)

This is a different distinction than that mentioned at
[“in” versus “of”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/193604/153448).

Comment: Great. I see the difference now. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yes; you'd use 'students of all non-science subjects'.